# Laravel validation does not work, always fails

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to make back-end validation for my form however it does not work. It always shows that validation failed even when I submitted the values.

## Code

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    array('email' => 'required'),
    array('password' => 'required')
));

if ($validation->fails()) { // This is always failing
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(Input::all());
    die();
}

die('everything is OK!');
```

## Output

```
Array
(
    [_token] => ZnzZ2aDoTABIZZkvwxZoa7IjHkvK25ndibis5AbA
    [email] => somedata
    [password] => somemoredata
)
```

As you can see it failed even tho it clearly showed from `Input:all()` that values are set.

Comment: extract the error and see why it is failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    array('email' => 'required'),
    array('password' => 'required')
));
```

to

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    'email' => 'required|email',  // Note that I added in valid email rule here also
    'password' => 'required'
));
```

Comment: shouldn't make any difference here.

Comment: What worked here is not the "email" flag, but fixing the **double array** error... see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required'
));
```

Not double array as you did :

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    array('email' => 'required'), // Is shouldn't be an array here.
    array('password' => 'required')
));
```

Comment: ^^ you got it brotha.